# How to send output from Excecute Process Task to stdout?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've got an Execute Process Task that is failing.  I'm capturing the output in StandardOutputVariable.  Right now when the package fails it just says it failed at Execute Process Task with no helpful information.  The StandardOutputVariable holds the exact failure message.  I'd like that message to be in stdout.  How do I do that?

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57613202/10376537

Comment: @TimMylott Yes, that does!  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a TaskFailed event handler to your "Execute Process Task" with a "Script Task" that fires a DTS event (Information, Warning or Error) with the content of the StandardOutputVariable as the event message.

[image: SSIS TaskFailed Event Handler]